# How to conditionally init an object in c#?

Tags: c#

I have an old function that sends off daily Sales Receipts to Quickbooks Online and wanted to also have it send off any Refund Receipts for any refunds that may have occurred.

The old main sale object is used throughout the function, having it's properties set as required. I would like to use this same bit of code for both Sales Receipts and Refund Receipts but Sales Receipts need sale set to a SalesReceipt Intuit object and Refund Receipts need the sale set to the Intuit RefundReceipt object.

I tried this:

```
if (inData.Product[d, l].Contains("Refund"))
{
    RefundReceipt sale = new RefundReceipt();
} else {
    SalesReceipt sale = new SalesReceipt();
}
```

But sale's scope is limited to the confines of the if/else block.

I could just duplicate the function but that seems messy for
just a simple assignment of an object.

Can I do this somehow?

TIA. :-)

Comment: So do `RefundReceipt` and `SalesReceipt` derive from a common `Receipt` class or similar? If so, declare the variable before your `if` statement with that type. (We basically don't have enough information at the moment.)

Comment: I'll look into that and give it a go if so - thanks.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? How are you going to process `sale` further down the code? If you expect to have more `if (type=refund) {...} else {...}`, then why don't you separate those from the beginning? If you expect to have common processing types must have some common base type that would allow such processing, otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

why you don' t use just object type

```
object sale;
if (inData.Product[d, l].Contains("Refund"))
{
     sale = new RefundReceipt();
} else {
     sale = new SalesReceipt();
}
```

use

```
func(sale as RefundReceipt);
```

or call function directly from code

```
if (inData.Product[d, l].Contains("Refund"))
{
     func(new RefundReceipt());
} else {
     func (new SalesReceipt());
}
```

Comment: in the last case how would `func` be declared, whats its arg,

Comment: @pm100 I don't have any idea, i am waiting for a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Serge answer you can do this

```
if (inData.Product[d, l].Contains("Refund"))
{
    func(new RefundReceipt());
} else {
    func(new SalesReceipt());
}
```

and func has

```
 void func(Object receipt){
    if(receipt is RefundRecipt)
    {
        var refund = receipts as RefundRecipt;
        ......
     }
     else
     {
        var refund = receipts as SalesRecipt;
        ....
     }
  }
```

however far better would be to have a clas heirarchy

```
 public abstract class Receipt{
 }

 public class SalesReceipt : Receipt{
 }

 public class RefundReceipt : Receipt{
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my absence. I've had my head in other stuff.
I finally just said let's quit being cute and just make two functions
one for SalesReceipts and one for RefundReceipts. Easier to debug, easier to maintain.

Thanks for all your help and suggestions, maybe it will help me or someone again sometime.

:Ron

Answer (score -2):

objects can be initialized with null

```
    if (inData.Product[d, l].Contains("Refund"))
{
    RefundReceipt sale = null;
 } else {
    SalesReceipt sale = null;
}
```

or if it is defined as List before the if and it has some value you can clear as follow

```
 sale.clear();
```

Comment: Oh, I tried .Dispose() but it wasn't found I'll try clear.

Comment: This will not solve the scoping problem in the OP at all. And there is no `clear()` method.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you are wrong , there is clear() method for the class object

Comment: @Developer: That is true in Python. This question is about C#.

Comment: @Developer: [This dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uoMzwE) shows the error I get when I try to use a `clear()` method. Can you create a fiddle showing how `clear()` works for you? Can you point me to the documentation for that method? The docs for the [Object class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0) don't mention it anywhere.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior here you go https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fe5rbb

Comment: @Developer: Gotcha. That's the `Clear()` method on the `List<>` class, not the `Object` class. I see you updated your answer to read "defined as List" in light of this. Calling `Clear()` on the list will remove all elements from the list: it still doesn't solve the OP's problem.